# How to help Tesseract read this quality of image

Tags: java, opencv, image-processing, ocr, tesseract

I've been looking for some help to train Tesseract, and I've managed to find some really good applications. However I think I'm trying to recognize some low quality images,  but I'm not sure.

So, will these images work or be 'trainable'? Is there anything that can be done to help (configs, image processing)? Note that I don't want only those images, but all images will be in the same pattern.

Images: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bs1Zj.jpg

Comment: Pretty sure you need to add your custom font type into their engine. I don't think it's a thing you can do yourself since it may not be a common font.

Comment: Actually it is, it's Arial, maybe Arial Black.